# Changing gnuplot range without affecting the origin

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to plot the graph a function (say y=x) in the range [-10:10] for both axes. If I write

```
gnuplot> set xrange [-10:10]
unset tics
set border 3
gnuplot> plot x
```

I get a graph in which the axes are centered on -10, -10, but I would like to have the axis centered in the origin 0, 0. How can I do this? I've tried by setting

```
set origin 0, 0
```

but it doesn't work.
Thank you.

Comment: `set origin` is for placing the origin of a subplot on the screen.  i.e. You can use it to shift the placement of the entire plot on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
 set zeroaxis
```

You can change the line type and line width by adding `linetype n` and/or `linewidth n`

Comment: Nice.  +1 from me.  (you can also change the `linestyle` using `ls n`).

Comment: Works fine for me too. Setting zeroaxis, border 0, tics axis. Thanks